# Remove space between letters in one world

Tags: sql-server, replace, space

I have string value which contains a long text. And there is last name of person write like this:

'S M I T H'.

So I have a long text in one row:

```
text text text 'S M I T H' John text text.
```

I find all these rows by this code:

```sql
Select *
from [dbo].[my_table]
where [TEXT] like ('% [A-Z][ ][A-Z][ ][A-Z][ ][A-Z]%')
```

But I don't know, how to remove the space between letters in the last name, so I want this:

```
text text text 'SMITH' John text text.
``
```

Comment: Is the last name *always* inside single quotes (`'`)? Can any other values be inside single quotes? Seems like you have a denormalised design, though; `LastName` should be it's own column, not a value inside a longer `(n)varchar` value.

Comment: No sometimes is single quotes and sometimes not. I know, this data is not good, but I don't have option do it better. So I have a longer varchar value with this space between letters in Last name :-)

Comment: So how do *you* know where the last name is, and, more importantly, how does SQL Server?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: I have only 3 columns - ID, Date and TEXT. In column Text is one sentenc and sometimes there is a name. First name is spelled correctly like John, Karl, Filip atc. Bud the last name is always whit this space. I don't know where is exactly, but after examining the data I know it is always a last name whit this problem.

Comment: You can copy my previous comment ##1-4, and use them as section headers in the original question. Otherwise, it is impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LEFT, RIGHT, SUBSTRING, REPLACE and CHARINDEX to do so...

An example :

```
WITH
T AS (SELECT 'text text text ''S M I T H'' John text text.' AS LONG_TEXT)
SELECT LEFT(LONG_TEXT, CHARINDEX('''', LONG_TEXT) - 1) + 
       REPLACE(SUBSTRING(LONG_TEXT, CHARINDEX('''', LONG_TEXT) ,  CHARINDEX('''', LONG_TEXT, CHARINDEX('''', LONG_TEXT) + 1) - CHARINDEX('''', LONG_TEXT) + 1), ' ', '') +
       RIGHT(LONG_TEXT, CHARINDEX('''', LONG_TEXT))
FROM T;
```